# Vuetify 3 v-list-group - collapse other sub-menus when opening group

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm using Vuetify 3 and I'm trying to implement a collapsible vertical menu inside the Vuetify navigation drawer using the v-list-group component. I need the currently expanded menu item to collapse when another menu item is clicked to expand (Accordion behavior). I've created the menu list, but the accordion effect does not work as expected.

Template:

```
<v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        temporary
        location="right"
        theme="dark"
    >
        <v-list density="compact">
            <v-list-group v-model="item.active" v-for="item in menuItems">
                <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
                    <v-list-item
                        :key="item.title"
                        v-bind="props"
                        :title="item.title"
                    ></v-list-item>
                </template>

                <v-list-item
                    v-for="subMenu in item.subMenuItems"
                    :key="subMenu"
                    :title="subMenu"
                ></v-list-item>
            </v-list-group>
        </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
```

Script:

```
<script setup>

const menuItems = ref([
    {
        title: "Menu Item 1",
        active: false,
        subMenuItems: ["Sub Menu Item 1", "Sub Menu Item 2", "Sub Menu Item 3"]
    },
    {
        title: "Menu Item 2",
        active: false,
        subMenuItems: ["Sub Menu Item 1", "Sub Menu Item 2", "Sub Menu Item 3"]
    },
    {
        title: "Menu Item 3",
        active: false,
        subMenuItems: ["Sub Menu Item 1", "Sub Menu Item 2", "Sub Menu Item 3"]
    }
])

</script>
```

In Vuetify 2, I could assign a variable to the `v-model` of `v-list-group` component, but this does not work with Vuetify 3 (Changing the value does not change the collapse/expand state).

The `v-list-group` component does not contain an `is-open` prop to manually modify its state (there is an `isOpen` flag which is passed to the activator slot, but it is read-only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, looks like that was changed, you need to do it using the surrounding `v-list` now.

The `:opened` property of `v-list` is an array that corresponds to which groups are opened. Which values are put into the list is determined by the `:value` property of `v-list-group`. To have at most  one group open, you can listen to the `@update:opened` event and fix the list accordingly.

So with a ref `opened = ref([])`, you can do:

```html
<v-list
  :opened="opened"
  @update:opened="newOpened => opened = newOpened.slice(-1)"
>
  <v-list-group
    v-for="item in menuItems"
    :key="item.title"
    :value="item"
  >
  ...
```

With `@update:opened="opened = $event.slice(-1)"`, all but the last element will be removed when the list is updated. This will close all groups except the one clicked last.

The `:value="item"` determines what will be put into the `opened` array. It does not really matter what it is, as long as it is unique for each group (unless you want items to open and close together, then they should have the same value).

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const {
  createApp,
  ref,
  computed
} = Vue;
const {
  createVuetify
} = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
createApp({
  setup() {
    const menuItems = ref([{
        title: "Menu Item 1",
        active: false,
        subMenuItems: ["Sub Menu Item 1", "Sub Menu Item 2", "Sub Menu Item 3"]
      },
      {
        title: "Menu Item 2",
        active: true,
        subMenuItems: ["Sub Menu Item 1", "Sub Menu Item 2", "Sub Menu Item 3"]
      },
      {
        title: "Menu Item 3",
        active: false,
        subMenuItems: ["Sub Menu Item 1", "Sub Menu Item 2", "Sub Menu Item 3"]
      }
    ])
    const opened = ref([])

    return {
      opened,
      drawer: ref(true),
      menuItems,
    }
  }
}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.9/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app" class="d-flex justify-center">
  <v-app>
    <v-card>
      <v-layout>

        <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" temporary>
          <v-list density="compact" :opened="opened" @update:opened="opened = $event.slice(-1)">
            <v-list-group v-for="item in menuItems" :key="item.title" :value="item">
              <template v-slot:activator="{props, isOpen}">
                    <v-list-item
                        v-bind="props"
                        :key="item.title" 
                        :title="item.title"
                    ></v-list-item>
                </template>

              <v-list-item v-for="subMenu in item.subMenuItems" :key="subMenu" :title="subMenu"></v-list-item>
            </v-list-group>
          </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>

        <v-main style="height: 500px;">

        </v-main>
      </v-layout>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.9/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am use property v-list "open-strategy"
It helps to select only one active element in the list

```
<v-list
   open-strategy="single"
>
```

Comment: Nice, it is a new prop introduced in the new version of Vuetify